# Why PageSpeed Tool complaints about browser caching even though it was configured

Tags: performance, browser-cache

I am confused as why the google page speed tool says i need to enable browser caching even though i had my static content cache configured in the web. config file.

this is how my config looks like:

and the response header is set correctly:
[my chrome network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR8PU.png)

but google still complaints about it: [google's analysis report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb8pM.png)

Thanks a lot

Comment: my config: clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed probably recommends you to cache static resources for longer time period.

Relevant excerpt from [PageSpeed documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching):

> We recommend a minimum cache time of one week and preferably up to one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently. If you need precise control over when resources are invalidated we recommend using a URL fingerprinting or versioning technique - see invalidating and updating cached responses link above.